# Is there a verb that reverses the source and the result of rendering (e.g. rendering a document from a template)?

Tags: verbs, computing

Suppose I have a template for creating documents, and I want to render a document from the template.  It would be grammatically correct to call this action "rendering a document" or "rendering a document from a template," but calling it "rendering a template" or "template rendering" would be grammatically incorrect, because the template isn't the object that's being produced -- it is the source from which the document is being produced.

Is there a verb that represents the action being done to the template when the document is rendered from it?

Comment: The document is **generated** from the template. As for a verb applied to the template, **expanding** or **instanciating** the template. (I am only familiar with "rendering" for computer graphics.)

Comment: @JamesRandom I'd agree, I might also use *rendering* when talking about PDFs from a source such as LaTeX, but other than that I'd been talking about graphics

Comment: In addition to PDFs and computer graphics, I've seen it used in web development:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/api/#rendering-a-context

Comment: You're *following a template*.

Comment: or *applying a template*.

Answer (score 1):

Reify (verb)

make something real, bring something into being, or make something concrete.

I made a PDF by reifying the template.

Comment: That doesn't seem a very common usage. I could only find examples related to a testing framework called Hypothesis.

Comment: My understanding is that it is common in certain areas of computer science.  Haskell apparently.  Ontologies.

Answer (score 0):

You could say that the template **guides**, **governs**, **controls**, **regulates**, or **directs** the document production process. That is, the template is essentially "in charge" (in an inanimate sense) of how the resulting document appears.

If you wish to use "template" as the object, you could say that the document production process **follows** or **refers to** the template. That is, the process **adheres to** or **complies with** or **satisfies** the template's requirements.

If you choose to use the term "rendering," (although I think "document production" is clearer) then the process is that of **rendering from a template** or **template-based rendering**.

Some rearrangement of these terms to different parts of speech is possible (e.g., "The template is being **followed**." or "a template-**driven** process).

Is this what  you were looking for?